# Plotting space defined by implicit equations via pure functions (ContourPlot3d, RegionPlot3D, Graphics3D)

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions, mesh

Is there a simple elegant way to plot any implicit curve or surface in 2D or 3D, given the input `reg` (list of intervals, i.e. cube) and `f` (list of pure functions, i.e. equations)?
For curves in 3D (i.e. 2 equations in 3 variables), `Contourplot3D` is problematic. Why does

```
Graphics3D[{Red,MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2+z^2-4==0&&x^2+y^2-1==0,{x,y,z}], 1]}]
```

work, but if I run

```
reg={{-2,2},{-2,2},{-3,3}}; f={#1^2+#2^2+#3^2-4&,#1^2+#2^2-1&}; 
tr=Transpose; n=Length@reg; e=Length@f; v=Table[Unique[],{i,n}];  
o={And@@Table[fi@@v==0,{fi,f}],Sequence@@tr@Prepend[tr@reg,v],PlotRange->All,ContourStyle->Red};
Graphics3D[{Red,MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[o[[1]],v],1]}]
```

it returns errors?

Answer (score 3):

```
o1 = {And @@ Table[fi @@ v == 0, {fi, f}], tr@Prepend[tr@reg, v]};

Graphics3D[{Red, MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion @@ o1], 1]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can define `o1` as:

```
o1 = {And @@ Table[fi @@ v == 0, {fi, f}], MapThread[Flatten[{##}] &, {v, reg}]};
```

Comment: Thank you! Ill leave the question open for a while, if someone has a solution how to plot all implicit sets in 2D or 3D in a unified way. If there's a simpler way to do all this, please let me know. Best regards!